# How to obtain new facebook access token

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, apache-flex, facebook-graph-api

I looked all over facebook api docs for FLEX and i couldn't find a way to obtain a new access token, can anyone please guide me how to that?

By the way , the only time I get error "access token" is when I try to get information from the api and using the parameter "since".

when I use this call, im getting a token error message

```
FacebookDesktop.api("me/likes?since=1319917311",handleFeed);
```

and when im using it without since

```
FacebookDesktop.api("me/likes",handleFeed);
```

I get no error message

anyway the main issue is how to obtain a new access token
10x!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use third argument of `FacebookDesktop.api` method to pass additional parameters:

```
FacebookDesktop.api("me/likes",handleFeed, {
  since:1319917311
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure but probably if you pass params as part of url, `access_token` of current user isn't added to request and only parameters from URL are used...